# Why Postgres dblink stopped working abruptly

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have migrated a database from Oracle to RDS Postgres. I have used `pragma autonomous_transaction` in Oracle for logging errors where rollback happens in case of error. Since there is no direct option in Postgres, I have been using `dblink` for independent commits.

I have created a function where dblink will execute a user-defined function with DMLs in a different session in my test environment. Part of the function which connects through dblink is mentioned below.

```
Perform * from dblink(connection_string, query_function_call) as p (ret boolean);
```

Now in Dev environment, I deployed this function through pipeline in the Postgres database and afterwards I installed dblink extension. But the function when executed throwed `'dblink does not exist'` error. I resolved it by re-deploying the function and it worked just fine.

But after few days, suddenly I started to get `'dblink does not exist'` error, this time even after re-deploying the function, I get the same error.

The extension could be seen in the `pg_extension` table, rebooted the instance and still the same issue persists.

I also checked using the `dblink_connect` function to test the connection which also returns `'dblink does not exist'` error. Restarting the database instance didn't help either.

Can someone help why this issue occurs? I heard from infrastructure team that dblink is not a good practice to use in Postgres. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the output of `select nspname from pg_extension e, pg_namespace n where e.extnamespace=n.oid and e.extname='dblink';`, and `show search_path;`?

Comment: Also, is that the _exact_ error message? If the issue is what I'm trying to rule out with the queries in the previous comment, I would have expected it to be something like `function dblink(<x>) does not exist`.

Comment: PostgreSQL error messages tell you what type of object it is that does not exist (table, column, function, extension, file, etc.).  Please give us the complete, real error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are that you changed your `search_path` so that you can only access `dblink` by including the schema name.